# WhatsApp Signup embedding & Setting up webhooks

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, whatsapp

I'm setting up the WhatsApp/Meta embedding tool and trying to make it automatically set up everything automatically for programmatic receiving and sending messages to WhatsApp.

The issue I'm facing is that I'm not receiving webhooks to my platform from incoming messages to the WhatsApp number I've set up through the embedding tool. These are all the steps my application is taking:

1. Allowing the user to go through the embedding tool
2. At the end, I receive a token from the embedding tool
3. I trade it in that token, for an access token
4. I use the debugToken endpoint to retrieve the Waba ID and User ID
5. I add the UserID as a System User with `Manage` role on that Waba ID
6. I get phone numbers & use the /register endpoint on the phone number ID to verify it
7. I use `/subscribed_apps` endpoint for that waba_id to register the app to that waba id
8. I use `/subscribed_apps` endpoint and override the callback url to go to the multi-tenant instance of the webhook receiver (I include the verify token and I get a success response back)

Now when I send a message to the WhatsApp number, nothing happens.

What I Expect:
I expect the webhook to be triggered and hit my webhook endpoint & send a message through the WhatsApp API

What happens:
I don't see the endpoint being hit at all in my logging

Below I'll include my code (they are all just methods) in the hope that it helps in understanding what I'm doing

```php
        $accessToken = $this->getAccessToken($authCode);
        $debugTokenResponse = $this->getDebugToken($accessToken);
        $wabaId = $this->getWabaIdFromResponse($debugTokenResponse);
        $userId = $this->getUserIdFromDebugTokenResponse($debugTokenResponse);

        $addUserResponse = $this->addSystemUser($wabaId, $userId, $accessToken);

        if(($addUserResponse->json()['success'] ?? false) !== true)
            throw new Exception('Could not add system user to WhatsApp Business');

        $getPhoneNumbersResponse = $this->getPhoneNumbers($wabaId, $accessToken);
        $firstPhoneNumberId = $getPhoneNumbersResponse->json()['data'][0]['id'];

        $this->registerPhoneNumber($firstPhoneNumberId, $accessToken);

        $subscribeAppResponse = $this->subscribeApp($wabaId, $accessToken);

        if(($subscribeAppResponse->json()['success'] ?? false) !== true)
            throw new Exception('Could not subscribe app to WhatsApp Business');

        $overrideCallbackResponse = $this->overrideCallbackUri(
            $wabaId,
            '{MY URL}',
            '{MY VERIFY TOKEN}',
            $accessToken
        );

        if (($overrideCallbackResponse->json()['success'] ?? false) !== true)
            throw new Exception('Could not override callback uri');
```