WhatsApp Signup embedding, user code is always malformed
I'm setting up the WhatsApp/Meta embedding tool and trying to make it automatically set up everything automatically for programmatic receiving and sending messages to WhatsApp.
The issue I'm facing is that I'm not a valid client code after successful . These are all the steps my application is taking:
Allowing the user to go through the embedding tool
At the end, I receive a token from the embedding tool
I want to trade it in that token, for an access token but facebook graph api throw an error saying "Malformed access token" or "This authorization code has expired".



    window.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
        if (event.origin !== "https://www.facebook.com" && event.origin !== "https://web.facebook.com") {
            return;
        }
        try {
            const data = JSON.parse(event.data);
            if (data.type === 'WA_EMBEDDED_SIGNUP') {
                // if user finishes the Embedded Signup flow
                if (data.event === 'FINISH') {
                    const {
                        phone_number_id,
                        waba_id
                    } = data.data;
                    console.log("Phone number ID ", phone_number_id, " WhatsApp business account ID ", waba_id);
                    // if user cancels the Embedded Signup flow
                } else if (data.event === 'CANCEL') {
                    const {
                        current_step
                    } = data.data;
                    console.warn("Cancel at ", current_step);
                    // if user reports an error during the Embedded Signup flow
                } else if (data.event === 'ERROR') {
                    const {
                        error_message
                    } = data.data;
                    console.error("error ", error_message);
                }
            }
            document.getElementById("session-info-response").textContent = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);
        } catch {
            console.log('Non JSON Responses', event.data);
        }
    });
    
    const fbLoginCallback = (response) => {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            const code = response.authResponse.code;
            // The returned code must be transmitted to your backend first and then
            // perform a server-to-server call from there to our servers for an access token.
            FB.api(
                "/debug_token?input_token=" + code,
                function (response) {
                    if (response && !response.error) {
                        /* handle the result */
                        console.log(response);
                        console.log('here12')
                    }
    
                }
            );
        }
        document.getElementById("sdk-response").textContent = JSON.stringify(response, null, 2);
    
    }
    
    const launchWhatsAppSignup = (e) => {
        event.preventDefault();
    
        // Launch Facebook login
        FB.login(fbLoginCallback, {
            config_id: '1707717083377865', // configuration ID goes here
            response_type: 'code', // must be set to 'code' for System User access token
            override_default_response_type: true, // when true, any response types passed in the "response_type" will take precedence over the default types
            scope: "business_management, whatsapp_business_management, whatsapp_business_messaging",
            extras: {
                setup: {},
                featureType: '',
                sessionInfoVersion: '2',
            }
        });
    }
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
            appId: '521724357037484',
            autoLogAppEvents: true,
            xfbml: true,
            version: 'v20.0'
        });
    };    

                        



Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks in advance

Anyone please help me here

I got the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77688705/whatsapp-signup-embedding-setting-up-webhooks
